# Customer Account Data API (through Aggcat) always returns 400 response code

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I set up an application with the Intuit Customer Account Data API and am running a Rails app using Aggcat gem (https://github.com/cloocher/aggcat). I had to replace my certificate and followed the instructions for OpenSSL found [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0015_create_an_cad_integration/0010_creating_x.509_public_certificates). Under My Apps I uploaded the new public certificate and changed the settings on Aggcat to use the new private key file generated with it.

I can run client.scope(1) but when I try to run anything else (such as client.institutions) I get a bad request error (400). Any ideas what the problem could be? I've tried re-generating the certificate multiple times and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

According IPP's site,

**400 - Bad Request represents** - If the URL or variables are not in the correct format this error will display.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0700_error_codes

I've not tried CAD calls using ruby but I use the sample JAVA app(IPP). 
You can run the sample java app ( by configuring the devkit logger in debug mode) and capture the raw request/response and URL(and parameters) and compare the same which you're getting in your ruby example. That might help you to debug these issues.

Otherwise, you can also try the other two ruby examples which are available here- 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits

- https://github.com/cheqbook/intuit_ids_aggcat
- https://github.com/rewardsummit/intuit_ids_aggcat

Thanks